# Designing a VPC: Subnets inside subnets

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

This question is exactly similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/731753/aws-vpc-design-issue-cidr-conflicts). It appears the OP didn't get a satisfactory answer — because he didn't accept the sole response that he received. We are basically following instructions posted on the AWS Startup Collection blog: *[Practical VPC Design: 301 level guidance from an AWS Solutions Architect](https://medium.com/aws-activate-startup-blog/practical-vpc-design-8412e1a18dcc)*. However, that article was posted on July 2014 so I'm not quite sure if it's outdated or it's just me who's misunderstood the instructions.

I've tried attaching code but that makes me unable to post my question — I assume StackOverflow's machine learning algorithms are at work here since my code is quite similar to code in that question and I'm thinking that my question is being flagged as one that already has an answer.

So how do I do this? Is the answer to that other question best practice?

**UPDATE:**

*"While the way the author lays out the CIDR breakdown may make it appear that there are subnets within subnets, the article says nothing about creating the subnets that way."*

Then **how** did the author do that?

*"You cannot create AWS VPC subnets within AWS VPC subnets."*

If this method is not creating AWS VPC subnets within AWS VPC subnets, then **what** is it?

Like I mentioned, that article is 2 years old and I started using VPC just the other day. **Was this method valid then but invalid now, or was it never valid on AWS VPC at all?**

Comment: Still best practice.

Comment: How does your question differ? You haven't really asked one.  What problem are you trying to solve? You don't carve subnets into subnets in VPC.  You just divide your supernet into non-overlapping subnets.  There is no hierarchy, there are no routers, so no need to e.g. assign a /21 to each AZ and then /22 underneath within the AZ.  Just put them where you need them in appropriate, non-overlapping blocks.

Comment: I'm not using this approach to solve a problem that I have. I'm experimenting — I'm a new AWS user trying to get a good grasp of the length and breadth of what's on offer and this appears like an approach I might employ in future. If I can't carve subnets into subnets in VPC, does that mean that blog post is misleading?

Comment: While the way the author lays out the CIDR breakdown may make it appear that there are subnets within subnets, the article says nothing about creating the subnets that way.  You cannot create AWS VPC subnets within AWS VPC subnets.  You could do some weird homebrew routing thing to simulate it if you really, really wanted to, but as that blog post says, don't treat a VPC like a datacenter.  Take it for what it is.  And what it is is a single supernet divided into a single level of subnets.

Comment: It appears my question wasn't well understood. I've made the necessary edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Was this method valid then but invalid now, or was it never valid on AWS VPC at all?

Yes, it was valid when written, and yes, it is valid now.

The referenced question does not really have enough information to determine what error was being made, but the author almost certainly was making an error, since what was being attempted was correct, in principle.

If by "subnet" we are talking about contiguous blocks of IP address space that can be described in CIDR notation then of course all subnets are "within" other subnets. That's why we call them "sub"-nets.

But when we say VPC doesn't have subnets within subnets, what we are talking about is that VPC has a simple routing implentation, where there is no concept of (or need to or capability to) *provisioning* any subnets other than the final ones, where systems with network interfaces are deployed.

```
Level 1 192.168.0.0/16 ... VPC supernet
 Level 2 192.168.128.0/18  Third AZ in region
  Level 3 192.168.130.0/23 Web servers
```

In this example, the subnet at Level 2 is logical/informational/organizational but is never actually declared or provisioned anywhere in VPC.  There could be any intermediate number of levels, but these are for your planning purposes only.  VPC is unaware of any subnet hierarchy you may be using, because it has no need to know.

The VPC itself is provisioned with the CIDR block at level 1, and the single "subnet" -- this time, I'n using the term to mean a *VPC subnet* -- shown at level 3 -- is declared as a subnet in VPC.

This VPC subnet now has a subnet-id, a label, and exists in VPC in a single AWS region, where I can deploy EC2 instances, RDS instances, etc., on that subnet.

Once I allocate those 512 addresses (192.168.130.0/23) to a VPC subnet, that's the only place they can be used in this VPC.

I can't, then, create a subnet such as 192.168.130.128/25 in my VPC, because that conflicts with 192.168.130.0/23, which has already been allocated.

It doesn't conflict with 192.168.128.0/18 because I didn't actually provision that subnet in VPC. The "subnet" (CIDR block) at that level -- level 2 from the example above -- is essentially only for my planning and organizational purposes, a documentation of my intentions, but VPC knows nothing about it.

In fact, even though I "planned" to use that block in my third availability zone, there is no technical limitation or performance implication if I later needed to use, say, 192.168.132.0/22 in an entirely different availability zone within my VPC.  It's organizationally sloppy, but functionally not a problem.  VPC has no concept that 192.168.128.0/18 is "in" my third availability zone, because in any real sense, it actually is not -- no such information is declared or provisioned.

You could just as easily carve up 192.168.0.0/16 into 256 /24 blocks¹ and assign them to subnets and purposes with the availavility zone for each subnet chosen with a random number generator.  But, don't do that.  Not because it won't work just as well from a throughput perspective... but because it's organizationally messy and because 256 addresses may be fewer than you wish you had allocated to each subnet.

That last part seems strange, since 256 addresses seems like a lot, but the problem you run into is when you provision services that need interfaces and addresses -- I'm specifically thinking about scalable things like EC2 auto scaling, ECS, spot instances, Aurora, Lambda, and Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) -- the provisioning process involves specifying which subnet(s) those services will live on.

In the case of ELB, for each subnet where an ELB is provisioned, you need 2 addresses available, at an absolute minimim, per subnet, per ELB, so that the ELB nodes can replace themselves if needed (ELB can transparently bring up a second node, make it live, then retire the first node, for whatever reason -- such as AWS-directed maintenance).  You'd of course also need additional addresses available for the ELB to scale itself up by adding nodes.  (I've seen them go as high as 8, but am not aware of any actual limit to the number of nodes an ELB can spawn to handle increased traffic.)

---

¹Okay, not technically, since there is a [default limit of 200 subnets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_Limits.html#vpc-limits-vpcs-subnets) in a single VPC, regardless of the block size.  This is a limit that AWS Support can increase on request, but a VPC with over 200 subnets probably has flaws incorporated into its design.

Comment: Thank you. Very useful information. Now I know a lot more about VPC.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I see where the confusion lay. The article *implies* that specific subnet *objects* are created for each of the layers.

```
10.0.0.0/18
   10.0.32.0/19
       10.0.32.0/20 - public
       10.0.48.0/20
           10.0.48.0/21 - protected
           10.0.56.0/21 - spare
```

You are not creating subnet *objects* for each item in the chart, you're only creating them for the leaf-nodes. In the above, these are the true subnets created:

- 10.0.32.0/20 - public
- 10.0.48.0/21 - protected
- 10.0.56.0/21 - spare

That's it. Everything else is probably on a subnet-planning spreadsheet somewhere and not represented in AWS directly. The rest of the article goes into some length about why you don't need to bother representing the entire address hierarchy in AWS. You only create subnets on the final subnets where things will be running.